# Why if statement is not entering when Null

Tags: c++, c

I have the next code, and when `raiz` is NULL is not entering the if statement

I already tried to do the other way like `if(raiz != NULL)` and  in the else statement trying to run the code :

```
masAlto = 1;
raiz = Nuevo;
```

Here is my code:

```
void InsertaAVL(arbolAVL *raiz, arbolAVL *Nuevo, int masAlto)
{
    arbolAVL *a = raiz;

    int subarbolmasAlto = FALSO;
    if (raiz == NULL)
    {
        masAlto = 1;
        raiz = Nuevo;
    }
    else
    { 
        if (raiz->llave > Nuevo->llave)
        {
            //Insertar a la Izquierda
            InsertaAVL(raiz->Izq, Nuevo, subarbolmasAlto);
            if (subarbolmasAlto == VERDADerO)
            {
                switch(raiz->FBalance)
                {
                    case LH : BalanceIzquierdo(raiz,masAlto);
                        break;
                    case RH : raiz->FBalance = EH;
                        masAlto = FALSO;
                        break;
                    case EH : raiz->FBalance = LH;
                        masAlto = VERDADerO;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
                masAlto = FALSO;
        }
        else
        {
            InsertaAVL(raiz->Der, Nuevo, subarbolmasAlto);
            if (subarbolmasAlto == VERDADerO)
            {
                switch(raiz->FBalance)
                {
                    case LH : raiz->FBalance = EH;
                        break;
                    case RH : BalanceDerecho(raiz,masAlto);
                        break;
                    case EH : raiz->FBalance = RH;
                        masAlto = VERDADerO;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
                masAlto = FALSO;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when `raiz` is NULL to enter the code inside the if statement

Comment: 1) There's no language called C/C++. It is either C, or C++. Which one of those do you have here? 2) What makes you think, that `raiz` is `NULL` here? Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger, while inspecting the values of variables? 3) Please provide [mcve].

Comment: If `raiz` is `NULL` then it will enter the if statement, You need to think about how you know what you think you know, what's the evidence? Clearly you are making a mistake somewhere, but you haven't provided any information here that would let anyone help you.

Comment: Also, please post code in English. Makes things much easier as it's the main language on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* enter the `if` statement `true` branch, although I'd prefer `if (!raiz)` as the conditional as this behaves well with the `NULL` of C and the `nullptr` of C++. Effectively though the `true` branch is a no-op since the assignments

```
masAlto = 1;
raiz = Nuevo;
```

have no effect on the quantities passed by the caller of the function. Did you want `int* masAlto` &c. as the parameters?